# Missing xtick labels from table in bar plot whenever y value is nan

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Given a picture like that:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
netname,index,gxccmean,gxprmean,gxssspmean
COMLJ,1,431.14445,919.70278,266.85096
SOCSINAWEIBO,2,20723.41791,nan,2827.05371
RGGN224S0,3,nan,12293.6209,340.84044
COMORKUT,4,1139.28039,2503.06515,622.09671  
}\realtable


\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    columns/realname/.style={string type},
                    legend style={at={(1.5,1)},anchor=north},
                    xtick style={draw=none},
                    ybar=0pt,
                    log origin=infty,
                    xtick style={draw=none},
                    xticklabel style={rotate=90,inner sep=0mm},
                    xtick=data,
                    xticklabels from table={\realtable}{netname},
                    ymode=log,
                ]
                    \addplot table [x=index, y=gxccmean] {\realtable};
                    \addlegendentry{Connected Components};
                    \addplot table [x=index, y=gxprmean] {\realtable};
                    \addlegendentry{Page Rank};
                    \addplot table [x=index, y=gxssspmean] {\realtable};
                    \addlegendentry{Single Source Shortest Paths};
                \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Whenever "gxccmean" y value is NaN, the xticklabels are not plotted. It seems that pgfplots only considers the first addplot in order to plot the tick labels. If I change the order of addplot table commands, the label is placed correctly (the y value for the second addplot is not NaN). Moreover, pgfplots shifts the label to the tick at the right side.

I'd not like to change the order of addplots. Thus, I wonder whether there is a way to force the xticklabels plotting:

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to the site! There are a couple of ways to fix this, but which one works best depends on your setup. Could you include the necessary parts of your `generalfigures2` style and a dummy data file that's set up the same way as your proper data file. Also, as Kurt says, it's always best to post a complete but minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`) that people can just compile straight away, without having to fill in the blanks themselves.

Comment: I posted a compilable code snippet.

Comment: Will your data always be sorted according to the `index` column? Does your `index` column always start at `1`, and will it always be "gapless"?

Comment: Yes to all questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is going to be plotted in the order that it appears in the table and the `index` column is not used to adjust the order or position of the bars, you can simply use

```
xtick = {1,...,20}
```

where `20` is just an arbitrary number that's greater than the number of rows in your table. This will generate a tick position at every integer value of x between 1 and 20.

Note that in this case, you could also do away with the `index` column entirely, and use `\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex] {...}` to generate the x positions automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
netname,index,gxccmean,gxprmean,gxssspmean
COMLJ,1,431.14445,919.70278,266.85096
SOCSINAWEIBO,2,20723.41791,nan,2827.05371
RGGN224S0,3,nan,12293.6209,340.84044
COMORKUT,4,1139.28039,2503.06515,622.09671  
}\realtable


\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    columns/realname/.style={string type},
                    legend style={at={(1.5,1)},anchor=north},
                    xtick style={draw=none},
                    ybar=0pt,
                    log origin=infty,
                    xtick style={draw=none},
                    xticklabel style={rotate=90,inner sep=0mm},
                    xtick={1,...,20},
                    xticklabels from table={\realtable}{netname},
                    ymode=log,
                ]
                    \addplot table [x=index, y=gxccmean] {\realtable};
                    \addlegendentry{Connected Components};
                    \addplot table [x=index, y=gxprmean] {\realtable};
                    \addlegendentry{Page Rank};
                    \addplot table [x=index, y=gxssspmean] {\realtable};
                    \addlegendentry{Single Source Shortest Paths};
                \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```